# Capybara 'visit' is not considering '#' character in URL?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Im running into a strange issue, I have my app host set to a remote site like so:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10 # seconds
  config.default_driver        = :selenium_chrome
  config.app_host              = 'https://dev.stagingsite.com/widget-web/#/'
end
```

All relative paths come after the `/#/`, so in my visit methods (such as `session.visit('login')` will take me to the URL:

https://dev.stagingsite.com/widget-web/login#/

I've tried adding '/' in various places, escaping the `#` but it seems to not be able to put relative url's after the `#` and instead always tries to put it after the `widget-web/`

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** Actually after thinking about this a while it would probably do what you want if you did `visit '#login'` since the fragment passed in visit would get merged over the app_host fragment

Capybara `visit` doesn't just append to `app_host` - it parses `app_host` and what's passed to `visit` and merges them. `visit` accepts either a full url or a relative path, what you're trying to set is the URL fragment - which `visit` has no way of identifying as what you want to do - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier. If you want to be setting the fragment in browser you're going to need to pass a full URL to `visit` (possibly by using your own helper function to build the URL you want)

Comment: @msmith1114 Updated the answer with a possible way to do what you want

Comment: That actually worked, it has to sorta auto-append an extra '/' on the url after the '#' but it seems to handle it ok

Answer (score 4):

From MDN's URL documentation:

> It is worth noting that the part after the **#**, also known as the **fragment identifier**, is never sent to the server with the request.

Check your server logs; you'll see that any request to `/widget-web/#/` is sent as a request to `/widget-web/`. The `#` prevents anything after it from being sent to the server.

[What is a URL? docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)